# How can I have WebStorm Recognize and provide auto-completion for component names inside a custom Angular Library?

Tags: angular, npm, webstorm

I'm currently having a problem with WebStorm recognizing a custom Angular library built using `generate library`. This library is published on NPM correctly - has all the umd, es2015, fes2015, etc. files and they are specified in the package.json. It's all done by the schematics, so it's probably correct.

I am correctly exporting all the modules and components into `public-api.ts`. Everything is accessible.

My project is using the published npm library correctly and is specifying the correct dependency and version of my custom library. Everything compiles and I can include components from this library into my Angular project, and I can see them in the browser rendering perfectly. Basically everything is working 100% except WebStorm doesn't detect any these components when using auto-complete like it does for other components.

I know for libraries like Material, WebStorm also works so I am curious what the Material developers did to get WebStorm to provide auto-completion here.

Does anyone have any idea?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have to include either your component sources (`.ts` files) or the `*.metadata.json` (https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/getting-your-angular-2-library-ready-for-aot-90d1347bcad) in your published library package in order to get your components recognized by the static code analysis